# Scala/Java : Compare two list/set and removed matched element from both list

Tags: scala, collections

I have two lists with two different types, but both types have the same field to identify/compare.

My Requirement: I want to compare two lists based on some fields of objects, once matched delete element from both list/set. 
For example:

```
    case class Type1(name:String, surname: String, address: Int)
    case class Type2(name:String, surname: String, address: Int, dummy: String)
```

So record will be matched if both lists have the same field data for both types.

My List:

```
    val type1List = List(Type1("name1","surname1", 1),
        Type1("name2","surname2", 2),
        Type1("name3","surname3", 3)
        )

    val type2List = List(Type2("name1","surname1", 1),
        Type2("name2","surname2", 2),
        Type2("name4","surname4", 4)
        )
```

Comparing  type1List and type2List, removed the matched date from both lists.
type1List should contain only:

```
    val type1List = List(
        Type1("name3","surname3", 3)
        )
```

type2List should contain only:

```
    val type2List = List(
        Type2("name4","surname4", 4)
        )
```

I tried it with looping/interation , but that seems too complex and performance hit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeh, each list contains unique elements. Actually it's huge list of transaction. No duplicate elements in both list.

Comment: which fields would be the identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not adjust the 2 *Types*, here a pragmatic solution:

First find the 'equals'

```
  val equals: Seq[Type1] = type1List.filter {
    case Type1(n, sn, a) =>
     type2List.exists { case Type2(n2, sn2, a2, _) =>
        n == n2 && sn == sn2 && a == a2
      }
  }
```

Then filter both Lists:

```
  val filteredType1List = type1List.filterNot(t1 => equals.contains(t1))
  val filteredType2List = type2List.filterNot {
    case Type2(n2, sn2, a2, _) =>
      equals.exists { case Type1(n, sn, a)=>
         n == n2 && sn == sn2 && a == a2
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic approach to the task.
The idea is to find the common elements in both lists according to some custom functions, and then remove both of them.

```
def removeCommon[A, B, K](as: List[A], bs: List[B])
                         (asKey: A => K)
                         (bsKey: B => K): (List[A], List[B]) = {
  def removeDuplicates[V](commonKeys: Set[K], map: Map[K, List[V]]): List[V] =
    map
      .iterator
      .collect {
        case (key, value) if (!commonKeys.contains(key)) =>
          value.head
      }.toList

  val asByKey = as.groupBy(asKey)
  val bsByKey = bs.groupBy(bsKey)

  val commonKeys = asByKey.keySet & bsByKey.keySet

  val uniqueAs = removeDuplicates(commonKeys, asByKey)
  val uniqueBs = removeDuplicates(commonKeys, bsByKey)

  (uniqueAs, uniqueBs)
}
```

Which you can use like following:

```
final case class Type1(name:String, surname: String, address: Int)
final case class Type2(name:String, surname: String, address: Int, dummy: String)

val type1List = List(
  Type1("name1","surname1", 1),
  Type1("name2","surname2", 2),
  Type1("name3","surname3", 3)
)

val type2List = List(
  Type2("name1","surname1", 1, "blah"),
  Type2("name2","surname2", 2, "blah"),
  Type2("name4","surname4", 4, "blah")
)

val (uniqueType1List, uniqueType2List) =
  removeCommon(type1List, type2List) { type1 =>
    (type1.name, type1.surname, type1.address)
  } { type2 =>
    (type2.name, type2.surname, type2.address)
  }

// uniqueType1List: List[Type1] = List(Type1("name3", "surname3", 3))
// uniqueType2List: List[Type2] = List(Type2("name4", "surname4", 4, "blah"))
```

Comment: I tried it, It has a compilation, filterKeys is not found.

Comment: @user1662067 oh my bad, that is because the method only exists on **Scala** `2.13`, I will edit the answer with a version that works for `2.12` too.

Comment: @user1662067 I have updated the answer, please give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what field you want to use to base your *diff* on, here is an outline of a solution.

First define a super class for both types:

```
abstract class Type(val name : String) {
  def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[Type]

  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case obj : Type => obj.canEqual(this) && this.name == obj.name
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode(): Int = this.name.hashCode
}
```

Then define your types as sub types of the above class:

```
case class Type1(override val name: String, surname: String, address: Int) extends Type(name)
case class Type2(override val name: String, surname: String, address: Int, dummy: String) extends Type(name)
```

Now a simple

```
type1List.diff(type2List)
```

will result in:

```
List(Type1(name3,surname3,3))
```

and

```
type2List.diff(type1List)
```

will give:

```
List(Type2(name4,surname4,4,dum3))
```

Still, I would be careful with solutions like this. Because circumventing `equals` and `hashcode` opens up the code to all kinds of bugs. So it is better to make sure this is kept limited to the scope you are working in.

Comment: Not working, type1List.diff(type2List) returning zero size list.

Comment: See a working version at [this link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/idu1pQKLRqqOxk3eqO7M8Q)

Comment: @user1662067 If you find this solution suitable for your problem, please consider accepting the answer or upvoting it. Thanks!

Comment: This works..For me.. I am still working on complexity and performance  of provided solution. I have kind of 1 Million element in each list?

Comment: Any idea what would be complexity of provided solution for if both list have 1 M records

Comment: @user1662067 `diff` puts collections in a set by default so the overall run time efficiency should be *O(n)*.

Comment: @user1662067 if run time efficiency is important to you, I suggest you create sets before applying the other solution you have accepted. In its current form, it is *O(n^2)* run time complexity.